# Calling a function in Android Started Service

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app to monitor changes in proximity sensor value. In app there should be two separate buttons to start a service and then to start monitoring proximity sensor.

This is my service class

```
public class MyService extends Service{

Sensor proxSensor;
SensorManager sm;
public static MyService instance;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    instance = this;
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public void startScan(){
    sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    proxSensor=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    SensorEventListener eventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            Log.e("Sensor","Value "+sensorEvent.values[0]);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
        }
    };
    sm.registerListener(eventListener, proxSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

I am starting service from my main activity

```
public void viewNotification(View view){
    startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
}

public void viewNotification2(View view){
    MyService.instance.startScan();
}
```

The Log output is printed correctly while the app is running but when I close the activity and remove it from previous apps list the output is not given. But if I call startScan() within onStartCommand it goes on running even after I close the app.

Why doesn't it keep on giving the output?
Is there any other method instead of using static MyService to achieve this?

Comment: bind the activity to the service, don't access it with static methods

Comment: So from what I see, you want the values of the sensor to still be printed out even after you close the application? Also do not call the service in a static way

Comment: I tried to bindService()  but then also sensor output is printed only if activity is alive. I want the service to run indefinitely

Comment: The issue here is the Service is restarting when the bounded app restarted. The solution is starting the service in a separate process as a foreground service.

Answer (score -2):

First of all - use service binding or aidl approaches for working with your Service. (see: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

For example:

Suppose, we have service named MyService. 
In this class you need write next

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalServiceBinder();

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class LocalServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getBinder() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

Next in your Activity:

```
private MyService mService;
boolean isBounded;
private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
            MyService.LocalServiceBinder binder = (MyService.LocalServiceBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getBinder();
            isBounded = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
            isBounded = false;
        }
    };
```

And

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (isBounded) {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            isBounded = false;
        }
    }
```

Now you can call your service methods like:

```
private void activityMethod(){
    if (isBounded){
        mService.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Second, for working in foreground, call startForeground (int id,           Notification notification) method.

Comment: Is it possible to bind to a started service?